# (scalaz) to optionally invoke a chained method

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have:

```
val having: Option[String] = ...

val averageStream = having match {
  case Some(expr) => stream[TimeMovingAverage].filter("name = '#name'").where(expr)
  case None       => stream[TimeMovingAverage].filter("name = '#name'")
}
```

Is there some scalaz magic that would eliminate the duplication?

I could do something like

```
val averageStream1 = stream[TimeMovingAverage].filter("name = '#name'")
val averageStream2 = having.map(averageStream1.where(_))
```

But that seems a bit awkward. I guess I am looking for something like

```
val averageStream = stream[TimeMovingAverage].filter("name = '#name'") |?| having.cata(_.where(_), _)
// Clearly some ambiguities with the _'s here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
stream[TimeMovingAverage].filter("name = '#name'") |> { str =>
  having.cata(str.where(_), str)
}
```

or even

```
stream[TimeMovingAverage].filter("name = '#name'") |> (
  having.cata(expr => _.where(expr), identity) : T => T
)
```

`T => T` must be changed to the  type of `stream[TimeMovingAverage]` which makes it less practical unless you find the following specialisation of `|>` in scalaz or define it yourself:

```
implicit def WrapIt[T](t: T) = new {
  def |~> (arg: T => T) = arg(t)
  def |?> (arg: Option[T => T]): T = arg.getOrElse(identity (_:T)).apply(t)
}

stream[TimeMovingAverage].filter("name = '#name'") |~> having.cata(expr => _.where(expr), identity)

stream[TimeMovingAverage].filter("name = '#name'") |?> having.map(expr => _.where(expr))
```

Not sure, if one should really come up with something like this, though.